# How to compare Json Arrays having elements not in same order

Tags: java, arrays, json, collections

I have 2 API responses and converted them into Json Array. When I convert 2 jsons into a map of key value pair the order of values are different and unable to perform comparison between 2 API responses.

JsonArray from API 1:

```
[
 {
  "employeeSalutation": null,
  "EmployeeName": "Example",
  "EmployeeCode": "SAA",
  "Zip": 12345,
  "DepartmentName": "Social science",
  "EmployeeAddress": "123 st",
  "StateCode": 9,
  "updatedDate": "2018-01-22T03:48:43.59",
  "EmployeeId": 1257
 }
]
```

Json Array from API 2:

```
[
 {
  "Emp_Name": "Example",
  "emp_Sal": null,
  "Dept_Name": "Social science",
  "Emp_addr": "123 st",
  "Zip": "12345",
  "Stat_cd": 9,
  "Emp_id": 1257,
  "upd_d": "2018-01-22 03:48:43.59",
  "Emp_Code": "SAA"
 }
]
```

I converted 2 Json Arrays into map of key-value pair with EmployeeId as key in Array 1 and Emp_id as key in Array 2. When I compare 2 maps the order of values in map are different and getting failed.

How to compare 2 APIs to ensure the values of each element in 2 apis are matched.

Comment: You might need to compare the attributes one by one

Comment: one by one will work for now since there is only 1 set of data. I also have apis which return data corresponding to multiple employee Ids.

Comment: Don’t compare them as Json Arrays. Compare them as `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to create a model which will represent these two `JSON` payloads. They are almost similar except of key names and values for `Zip` key where in first payload it is a number primitive in second - `String` primitive. Dates also have different format so you need to handle them by implementing custom date deserialiser.

Definitely you should use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library which allows to deserialise `JSON` to `POJO` model, provide custom date deserialisers, any many other features.

Below example provide example solution:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonApi1 = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();
        File jsonApi2 = new File("./resource/test1.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
                    private final SimpleDateFormat formatWithTimeZoneIndicator = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SS");
                    private final SimpleDateFormat formatWithoutTimeZoneIndicator = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SS");

                    @Override
                    public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                        String date = json.getAsString();
                        try {
                            return formatWithoutTimeZoneIndicator.parse(date);
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            try {
                                return formatWithTimeZoneIndicator.parse(date);
                            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                                throw new JsonParseException(e1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .create();

        Type employeesType = new TypeToken<List<Employee>>() {}.getType();
        try (FileReader readerApi1 = new FileReader(jsonApi1);
             FileReader readerApi2 = new FileReader(jsonApi2)) {
            List<Employee> employees1 = gson.fromJson(readerApi1, employeesType);
            List<Employee> employees2 = gson.fromJson(readerApi2, employeesType);

            System.out.println(employees1);
            System.out.println(employees2);
            System.out.println(employees1.equals(employees2));
        }
    }
}

class Employee {

    @SerializedName(value = "employeeSalutation", alternate = {"emp_Sal"})
    private String employeeSalutation;

    @SerializedName(value = "EmployeeName", alternate = {"Emp_Name"})
    private String employeeName;

    @SerializedName(value = "EmployeeCode", alternate = {"Emp_Code"})
    private String employeeCode;

    @SerializedName("Zip")
    private JsonPrimitive zip;

    @SerializedName(value = "DepartmentName", alternate = {"Dept_Name"})
    private String departmentName;

    @SerializedName(value = "EmployeeAddress", alternate = {"Emp_addr"})
    private String employeeAddress;

    @SerializedName(value = "StateCode", alternate = {"Stat_cd"})
    private int stateCode;

    @SerializedName(value = "updatedDate", alternate = {"upd_d"})
    private Date updatedDate;

    @SerializedName(value = "EmployeeId", alternate = {"Emp_id"})
    private int employeeId;

    public String getEmployeeSalutation() {
        return employeeSalutation;
    }

    public void setEmployeeSalutation(String employeeSalutation) {
        this.employeeSalutation = employeeSalutation;
    }

    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }

    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

    public String getEmployeeCode() {
        return employeeCode;
    }

    public void setEmployeeCode(String employeeCode) {
        this.employeeCode = employeeCode;
    }

    public JsonPrimitive getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(JsonPrimitive zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    public String getDepartmentName() {
        return departmentName;
    }

    public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
    }

    public String getEmployeeAddress() {
        return employeeAddress;
    }

    public void setEmployeeAddress(String employeeAddress) {
        this.employeeAddress = employeeAddress;
    }

    public int getStateCode() {
        return stateCode;
    }

    public void setStateCode(int stateCode) {
        this.stateCode = stateCode;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedDate() {
        return updatedDate;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDate(Date updatedDate) {
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }

    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Employee employee = (Employee) o;
        return stateCode == employee.stateCode &&
                employeeId == employee.employeeId &&
                Objects.equals(employeeSalutation, employee.employeeSalutation) &&
                Objects.equals(employeeName, employee.employeeName) &&
                Objects.equals(employeeCode, employee.employeeCode) &&
                Objects.equals(zip.getAsString(), employee.zip.getAsString()) &&
                Objects.equals(departmentName, employee.departmentName) &&
                Objects.equals(employeeAddress, employee.employeeAddress) &&
                Objects.equals(updatedDate, employee.updatedDate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(employeeSalutation, employeeName, employeeCode, zip, departmentName, employeeAddress, stateCode, updatedDate, employeeId);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "employeeSalutation='" + employeeSalutation + '\'' +
                ", employeeName='" + employeeName + '\'' +
                ", employeeCode='" + employeeCode + '\'' +
                ", zip=" + zip +
                ", departmentName='" + departmentName + '\'' +
                ", employeeAddress='" + employeeAddress + '\'' +
                ", stateCode=" + stateCode +
                ", updatedDate='" + updatedDate + '\'' +
                ", employeeId=" + employeeId +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
[Employee{employeeSalutation='null', employeeName='Example', employeeCode='SAA', zip=12345, departmentName='Social science', employeeAddress='123 st', stateCode=9, updatedDate='Mon Jan 22 03:48:43 CET 2018', employeeId=1257}]
[Employee{employeeSalutation='null', employeeName='Example', employeeCode='SAA', zip="12345", departmentName='Social science', employeeAddress='123 st', stateCode=9, updatedDate='Mon Jan 22 03:48:43 CET 2018', employeeId=1257}]
true
```

Comment: BTW, if you are using `Jackson`, you can use `@JsonAlias`(since 2.9.0) for deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

`JSONAssert` librairy is very handy for such tasks.

Here is [good tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jsonassert) on how to use it.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing this in Java, I suggest you map this values into Java objects.
That way, it would be extremely easy for you to compare values. You can use libraries like Gson for that but here i will show you how to do that without a library.

Create a class which will be easy to use for your API responses:

```
public class Employee {

 private String employeeSalutation; //i am not sure what type should this variable be
 private String employeeName;
 private String employeeCode;
 private int zip;
 private String departmentName;
 private String employeeAddress;
 private int stateCode;
 private String updatedDate;
 private int employeeId;

 //this is where your parser can be used
 public Employee(String employeeSalutation, String employeeName, String employeeCode, 
   int zip, String departmentName, String employeeAddress, int stateCode,String updatedDate, int employeeId){
     this.employeeSalutation = employeeSalutation;
     this.employeeName = employeeName;
     this.employeeCode = employeeCode;
     this.zip = zip;
     this.departmentName = departmentName;
     this.employeeAddress = employeeAddress;
     this.stateCode = stateCode;
     this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
     this.employeeId = employeeId; 
 }
//getters, setters 
}
```

Now you could have a class which will be used to convert this arrays into Java Objects, lets call it EmployeeConverter:

```
public class EmployeeConverter { 

  public Employee convertApi1Employee(String json){
  //since you didn't clarify how are you accessing your Json values, i will now use pseudo-code to finish my answer.

    //using variable.value pseudo-code to access json property value
    return new Employee(employeeSalutation.value, EmployeeName.value, EmployeeCode.value, Zip.value, DepartmentName.value, EmployeeAddress.value, EmployeeAddress.value, StateCode.value, updatedDate.value, EmployeeId.value);        
  }
}
```

You should create method convertApi2Employee() which will have exact functionality as convertApi1Employee() method, but will use different JSON object.

I hope this helps.